# How to add Scrollbars to Jquery Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a JQuery dialog on an page which opens to depending upon the size of the window. Unfortunately, I have been able to achieve in the containing div that is shown by the dialog a horizontal scrollbar when the minWidth of the containing div is reached in order that a user can scroll to the rest of the content. My relevant code snippet is as follows:

```
   $('#containingDiv').dialog({modal:true,
                              autoOpen:false,
                              height:heightOfWindow,
                              width:widthOfWindow,
                              resizable:true});

  $('#containingDiv').dialog('open');

  /*css Code for containing Div element*/
  #containingDiv{
                 min-height:900px;
                 min-width:900px;
                 overflow-x:auto;
                 overflow-y:hidden;
                 }
```

So, how can I achieve a position where if the dialog goes beyond the min-width of the containing div that the dialog window can then scroll to the content of the div?

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: I don't think it's a `min-width` you want to use, as that's only defining what the smallest is could be, not the largest - so it can always go greater than 900px. If you're wanting it to scroll past 900px, just set the `width:900px`.

Comment: When I mean beyond I mean less than 900px not greater

Comment: If the content is in a div which is less than 900px, what's the need for scrolling? Sorry but I'm completely lost here.

Comment: What I am trying to achieve here is when the hosting page is in small window size lets say a width of 780, and the dialog is then opened, because then dialog is set to detect the small window size. Now, because the containing div has a set limit, I want the a scrollbar to appear in order to allow the user to scroll across element

Comment: Have you tried to set overflow:scroll?

Comment: Yes same effect doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by creating another inner div with min-width and the outer div with width along with overflow-x. This will provide the scrollbar to the dialog.